# Iterate and select every two elements of a list python

Tags: python, list

I have the list below and I am able to create some other lists using every 2 combinations like this:

```
my_list = ['cc','th','ab','ca','cd']
from itertools import combinations
combi_2 = list(combinations(my_list,2))
print(combi_2)
```

I got this result:

```
[('cc', 'th'), ('cc', 'ab'), ('cc', 'ca'), ('cc', 'cd'), ('th', 'ab'), ('th', 'ca'), ('th', 'cd'), ('ab', 'ca'), ('ab', 'cd'), ('ca', 'cd')]
```

Using a parser, I am able to remove the ( ) and have a long list like this:

```
combi_2 = ['cc', 'th', 'cc', 'ab', 'cc', 'ca', 'cc', 'cd', 'th', 'ab', 'th', 'ca', 'th', 'cd', 'ab', 'ca', 'ab', 'cd', 'ca', 'cd']
```

Now, I want to iterate and select every 2 elements of this new created list without combination. What I want is something like this as output:

```
['cc', 'th' ], ['cc', 'ab'],...
```

I tried using this code:

```
for i, j in(combi_2):
    print(i,j)
```

but what I get is something like this:

```
['c','p']
```

How to do this properly ?

Comment: What is the `naive_bfs` function?

Comment: @M-Chen-3 I edited the question, it was a typo

Comment: Why is the list of tuple not good? if you leave it as is you can use `for i, j in combi_2 `

Comment: What's the point of splitting up the tuples if you immediately want to merge them again?

Comment: @PaulM. This would work, maybe I should do it that way and use the parser after. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
[list(subset) for subset in combinations(my_list, 2)]
```

---

```
[['cc', 'th'],
 ['cc', 'ab'],
 ['cc', 'ca'],
 ['cc', 'cd'],
 ['th', 'ab'],
 ['th', 'ca'],
 ['th', 'cd'],
 ['ab', 'ca'],
 ['ab', 'cd'],
 ['ca', 'cd']]
```